# Java Generics -- What am I missing?

Tags: java, generics

I am wondering if ya'll can help me get a better grip on generics.
I have simplified this question as much as possible.

I am trying to save the element stored in a linked list in a variable called saveIt.  I know LinkedList itself uses generics, so I want my variable to take up whatever data type is in the list.  I believe LinkedList itself designates that type as E, but when I try to declare a variable as 'E saveIt' I get "cannot resolve symbol E."

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // whatever goes here ...
    }

    void saveElement(LinkedList input) {
        E saveIt = input.getFirst();
    }
}
```

If I make the LinkedList then I can declare a variable as 'Integer saveIt' but that isn't what I want to do.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // whatever goes here ...
    }

    void saveElement(LinkedList<Integer> input) {
        Integer saveIt = input.getFirst();
    }
}
```

I considered declaring 'Object saveIt' but I'm not sure whether that is the right approach.  The concept of datatype E obviously exists in Java, and isn't quite the same as Object (or is it?), so why can't I access it (or how can I access it)?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // whatever goes here ...
    }

    void saveElement(LinkedList input) {
        Object saveIt = input.getFirst();
    }
}
```

So, basic question is if I want to have my method address whatever datatype is in the list, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<E> void saveElement(LinkedList<E> input) {
    E saveIt = input.getFirst();
}
```

You need to tell Java that `E` is a type parameter of your method -- it's like another thing that's being passed in! -- and that the `LinkedList` contains elements of type `E`.

Comment: Seriously?!  Wow.  That was easy (I did search quite a while before asking--maybe it's just supposed to be obvious).  Thanks.

Comment: this is equivalent to just `void saveElement(LinkedList<?> input)`

Comment: Depends what else gets done with the value and if the rest of the code needs to mention E.  I assumed this wasn't the OP's complete code.